# Jetpack Compose: LazyColumn align each item separately

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to align each item in a column one by one. I believe it's possible in simple `Column` using `align` operator like that:

```
Column {
   Text(text = "First", modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Start))
   Text(text = "Second", modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.End))
   Text(text = "Third", modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Start))
}
```

However I cannot find `align` operator for `LazyColumn` in appropriate scopes. How to do it in `LazyColumn`? I'm not interested in `horizontalAlignment` as it applies to all items.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68566402/how-can-i-align-different-items-inside-lazycolumn-in-jetpackcompose/68566565#68566565

Comment: Weirdly I couldn't manage to find that answer, that will work, thanks. Still hoping that Jetpack Compose team will add align operator for Lazy composables.

Answer (score 11):

You can wrap each item in a `Box` and then apply alignment within the `Box`.

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    Text(text = "First", modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter))
}
```

Another solution is to use 2 modifier attributes:

```
Text(
    text = "Your text here",
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .wrapContentWidth(align = Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
)
```